# Examples of well coded cocoa iPhone apps on github

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

Hi Im looking for examples of well written *Cocoa Touch* iPhone apps to help me see what good cocoa code looks like.

Specifically im interested in how people have layed out standard navigation apps.

I am also interested in how different people have layed out the model/view/controller files as well as general naming conventions etc.

Code which uses core data would also be interesting to see.

Comment: Actually, the framework used for iPhone apps is Cocoa *Touch*, as opposed to just Cocoa which is for Mac OS X. But I'm just nitpicking.

Comment: Why limit this to github? Anything with source available should do, no?

Comment: Some more that I know, but not in github (maybe in google code or other svn) is : [Core Plot](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/) [Wordpress for Iphone](http://iphone.wordpress.org/development/)

Comment: Version 1 of iOctocat is also open source, see https://github.com/dennisreimann/ioctocat It's a GitHub app for the iPhone and iPad.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Note: These are all super old apps by now, so they probably aren't good examples any more.

---

Erica Sadun's iphone 3.0 cookbook: http://github.com/erica/iphone-3.0-cookbook-

AppStore reviews scraper: http://github.com/gambcl/AppReviews

App Sales mobile for daily sales: http://github.com/omz/AppSales-Mobile

This one will teach you how to use the accelerometer pretty well:  http://github.com/haqu/tweejump

The Yammer iphone app: http://github.com/yammer/iphone

Reddit's iphone app: http://github.com/reddit/iReddit

Port of the old gorilla's game: http://github.com/Lamentum/Gorillas

Matt Gallagher's audio streamer: http://github.com/mattgallagher/AudioStreamer

**More:**

31 apps in 31 days: http://www.appsamuck.com/

wikiHow source: http://github.com/keishi/wikihow-iphone-app

tetris alternative: http://code.google.com/p/tris/

twitter client: http://github.com/takuma104/ntlniph

molecules: http://sunsetlakesoftware.com/2008/10/02/molecules-source-code-now-available

time tracking: https://github.com/lessallan/freshbooks-iphone-project

a ton more from matt gallagher: http://projectswithlove.com/projects/index.html

a list of even more: http://maniacdev.com/2010/06/35-open-source-iphone-app-store-apps-updated-with-10-new-apps/

and more... http://visionwidget.com/resources/icons-png/509-open-source-iphone-apps-in-app-store.html

a *new* one called Briefs.app which should interest everyone here: http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2010/08/briefsapp.html and http://github.com/capttaco/Briefs

and more.. just kidding.  that's all i got

Comment: Just a small comment; the Yammer app is far from well coded.

Comment: This is a stunning piece of code beautifully designed - https://github.com/facebook/three20

Comment: @Sid lol.. stunning piece of birds nest.  might be pretty to look at, not so pretty to understand